# How to load Partial Views using Radio button in mvc4 asp.net razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have two registration types. One is Individual and second as Business type registration. 
I have two radio buttons. I have used Html Helper for this. When I click on first radio button 
the individual partial view should be loaded. How can I achieve this using ap.net mvc4 razor

Comment: This question is very broad and probably opinion-based. It also doesn't show any research effort, any code samples or outline any problems that you ran in to. The short answer is that you should use a javascript framework (Angular is my choice) and WebApi. Where to go from there depends on your data and your business logic requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX to make a request to the controller within a [radio button's change function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142300/javascript-jquery-radio-button-click). In the controller action with an HttpPost or HttpGet decoration, you would return a [partial view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22124183/return-partial-view-with-model-c-sharp-mvc4). Within your ajax response you would recieve it as `dataType:'html'` and [place the result inside of a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23228779/jquery-ajax-post-success-will-not-update-div-displays-partial-view).

Google is your best friend when you're learning.